# Styling border for material-ui Card component

Tags: css, material-ui, border, border-radius

I'm trying to give a border to a `material-ui` Card component. The component already has a border-radius and the border gets cut off on the rounded edges.
Demo : https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-card-border-cqdh3q?file=/index.js